# C Programming find all the words in a random string

Tags: c, string

Say I have a very random string such as:

```
"%^&%thank*(^  ^&* you&*^^guys"
```

What is the most efficient way to find all the words in the string? Without checking the string character by character?

Here I wrote how I would have done this due to request

```
int length(char *c) {
    int n = 0;

    while(*(c+n)){
        n++;
    }
    return n;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 
    int n;
    int m=0;
    int count=1;

    if(argv[1]==NULL) {
        printf("%s","error" );
    }

    while(argv[count]!=NULL){
        n=length(argv[count]);
        while(m!=n){
            if('a'<argv[count][m]<'z'){
                //do stuff
            }
        }
        count++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This isn't a site to dump your homework. Please show what you've tried, and describe what went wrong.

Comment: @Carcigenicate This is not my homework. I have done it by going over the string character by character to check if it is alphabet. I just wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: "I have done it by going over the string character by character " --> post that code to clarify your intent and how best to help answer this question.

Comment: Do you have a definition of a "word"?

Comment: @jww yesterday Hi, the definition of a word can be anything consist of one of multiple alphabet capitalized or not, like;"a","Adas","dSsDa","Dd". It doesn't need to have meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use [`strtok(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) to parse the string at multiple delimiters. In terms of making this work for random strings, you might need to have a collection of all the possible delimiters that could occur. 
Here is a very basic example of using `strtok()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char str[] = "%^&%thank*(^  ^&* you&*^^guys";
    const char *delim = "%^*(& ";

    char *word = strtok(str, delim);
    while (word != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", word);
        word = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is a more useful method, which collects the delimiters from `str`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXCHAR 256

int main(void) {
    char str[] = "%^&%thank*(^  ^&* you&*^^guys";
    int count[MAXCHAR] = {0};
    char *word;
    unsigned char curr;
    size_t charcount = 0, numbytes = strlen(str);
    char delim[numbytes+1];

    for (size_t i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        curr = str[i];
        if (!isalpha(str[i]) && count[curr] == 0) {
            delim[charcount++] = str[i];
            count[curr] = 1;
        }
    }
    delim[charcount] = '\0';

    word = strtok(str, delim);
    while (word != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", word);
        word = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This solution uses a hashing `O(n)` approach for only adding unique delimeters. This is a possible solution, but the approach of going through character by character is more efficient. This is because all you need is a temporary buffer to store the *current* word being processed, and once a non alpha character is seen, terminate the buffer and start again.

Comment: Thanks, it indeed will take a while to add all the delimiters tho lol.

Comment: @GhostKidYao Not really. Now that I think about it, you could simply loop over `str`, and add non alpha characters to `delim`. Then simply use `delim` with `strtok()`. This is a very efficient way.

Comment: True it's way better then checking if each character is alphabet

Comment: "This is a very efficient way"  --> Disagree.  `delim[]` will consists of redundant examples of delimiters - (`"%^&%*(^  ^&*&*^^";`)  reducing efficiency of `strtok()`.

Comment: @RoadRunner From an "efficiency" view, a single pass through the string is hard to beat.  Unclear why OP does not want to use that effective character by character approach.

Comment: Got it. I just started programming so I figured that going through string character by character seems to be the most simple way and "highly likely" not the best way lol